# Rspec fails for Devise model custom validation for valid_password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am using devise gem(authentication). I am implementing custom validation for reset password.  User can not reset there new password with existing password.
in **user** model code is:

```html
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
     validate  :check_existed_password                               

      def check_existed_password
        if User.find_by_email(self.email).valid_password?(password)
          errors.add(:password, "password already existed, try other")
        end
      end
    end
```

After running rspec, I am getting error:  Failure/Error: no_email_user.should_not be_valid
   NoMethodError:
       undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass. All pre-existing test cases in user_spec.rb file is getting fail. any suggestion ?

> Blockquote

Comment: Which Rails version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `email` is not present or the `email` you are providing doesn't has any user associated with it. This is why you are geeting the error. As in the spec you are checking `no_email_user.should_not be_valid` means user with no email should not be valid. The validation you have added `check_existed_password` needs to only run on `update` and not on create. So make it as:

```
validate  :check_existed_password, :on => :update
```

Beacuse the user will reset password on update action and not on create.
Currently it will try to find a user which has not been created yet and throw error everytime.

Hope this helps.